# Select with not exist in the same table with multiple fields

Tags: sql, oracle, exists

I need to select registers from table that not exist in the same table. I mean if i have this table:

```
ID   VALUE1   VALUE2   VALUE3
1      1         1        1
2      2         2        1
3      3         4        1
4      1         5        1
5      2         2        2
6      3         4        2
7      1         8        2
8      2         2        2
```

The result of the query should be

```
ID   VALUE1   VALUE2   VALUE3
1      1         1        1
4      1         5        1
```

Because the rest of the values are the same for the value1 and value2 but diferent value3. I mean the row 2 of the table is the same that the row 5.

I try to do something like but not works:

```
select t1.value1, t1.value2 from table1 t1 where value3=1
and not exist 
(select t2.value1, t2.value2 from table2 t2 
where t1.value1=t2.value1 and t1.value2=t2.value2 and value3=2)
```

Thank you in advise and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
 WHERE T1.VALUE3 = 1
   AND NOT EXISTS 
       (SELECT 1 
          FROM YOUR_TABLE T2
         WHERE T1.VALUE1 = T2.VALUE1
           AND T1.VALUE2 = T2.VALUE2)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, i know not exist is the key but i use it in the wrong way :(

Answer (score 1):

I think `not exists` does what you want:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.value3 = 1 and
      not exist (select 1
                 from table2 t2 
                 where t2.value1 = t1.value1 and
                       t2.value2 = t1.value2 and
                       t2.value3 = 2
                );
```

That said, you can also use window functions:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             max(value3) over (partition by value1, value2) as max_value3
      from table1 t1
      where value3 in (1, 2)
     ) t1
where max_value3 = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are on the right track with `exists`.

I would phrase your query like:

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1 
where 
    t1.value3 = 1
    and not exist (
        select 1 from table1 t2 
        where t1.value1 = t2.value1 and t1.value2 = t2.value2 and t2.value3 = 2
    )
```

Key points:

- the `exists` subquery should be `from table1` (your query uses `table2` but it seems like this table does not actually exists)
- you don't actually need to return columns  from the `exists` subquery, since all it does is check if *some row* is produced - hence the `select 1`